# iOS: When viewing details by clicking on table cell, can't navigate from UITableView Detail View back to Master View

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have built a Master/Detail table using a Storyboard (summary setup image below). It's badly done with the navigation controllers, but unfortunately I've gone too far to turn back now. I am running in iOS 6, if relevant.

My problem is that when navigating from the Master view to the Details View through the 'Add' button on my Master View (which works via segue code), the 'Done' button code successfully brings me back to the Master View. However, if I have navigated to the Details View by clicking on a cell (via *didSelectRowAtIndexPath*), clicking 'Done' pushes me back to the view that instantiated and pushed the storyboard.

**didSelectRowAtIndexPath:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
     DetailsViewController *detailView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddDetails"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
  }
```

I have tried everything I can come up with to return to the Master Table View, but nothing I try is working. I have tried:

```
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

and

```
   MasterViewController *masterView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"masterView"];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:masterView animated:YES];
```

Here is the image of my Storyboard setup:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a very strange arrangements of controllers. In particular you have two navigation controllers.

i suggest ad arrangement with a single navigation controller with the master as the root controller. When you go from master to detail controller you do it in the *same* navigation controller.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

popViewController is the right call to make when using detail views and navigation controllers.  If that is not working something is terribly wrong, since you have successfully used a navigation controller to push.

Basically you have to be able to get to the same navigation controller you used to push, when doing a pop.  You might even consider setting a custom navigation controller property on that detail view, and assigning it at the time you do the push - then use it to pop also.

Comment: _Basically you have to be able to get to the same navigation controller you used to push, when doing a pop_    That sounds like the problem. But how can I reference the right navigation controller? A code example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I outlined it in the answer - set a UINavigationController property on the detail view, set it before you do the pushViewController.  In the detail view use the property to pop the view controller instead of self.navigationController.